# Indetify people in images

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

there are many sites or albums where you upload your image and you can get a directory of images you appear in. (each person will have in his group all images where he appears in)
I want to write such an app and couldn't find library/ implemented algorithm is there any code or libs I can use for this?

Comment: Unclear: "program groups the different images into the groups of people."

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward package is http://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/labeled_faces.html. This however is just a sample and you will likely have to extensively train your algorithms to get the desired results.